# Output All SQLite3 Database Tables in Command Line Shell

Tags: windows, sqlite

I am trying to use the SQLite3 Command Line Shell application to print out all tables in my database.

**My Problem:** When I type the command `.tables` nothing gets print out? I am unsure I am even connecting/opening the database because the application doesn't print out any status such as 'opened db' or anything.

One thing I know for sure is that my database file exists and contains tables and rows. I know this because my C# application is updating and querying the db just fine.

Below is my commands. How can I print out all my databases tables? Am I doing something wrong?

[image]

[Full Size Picture](http://i60.tinypic.com/2r3crpx.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `.open` probably created another database somewhere else.

Use a command prompt, and run it like this instead:

```
sqlite3.exe "Full_filename_of_your_db_file"
```

This works for me.

--

Edit: Alternatively, `.open` with single quote can also do the job

```
.open 'Full_filename'
```